# How to count parent's property with linq

Tags: c#, linq, wpfdatagrid

I have 2 object collections looking like this

```
public class Meter
    {
        public string UID { get; set; }
        public string NR { get; set; }
        public List<GMSData> data { get; set; }
    }

public class GSMData : Meter
    {
        public DateTime TimeStamp { get; set; }
        public int CellID { get; set; }
    }

 public static List<Meter> GetMeterUIDList()
        {
            return meters.Values.ToList();
        }
        public static List<GSMData> GetGsmdataList()
        {
            return meters.Values.SelectMany(m => m.Gsmdata)
                .OrderBy(t => t.TimeStamp)
                .ToList();
        }
```

I need to get all NR for each CellId and a count on how many NR there are on each CellID.
How can i do that?

Comment: Two collections? Show them.

Comment: It looks we do not have a complete picture of your question. Do you have a List<GSMData> or what are you trying to do :)

Comment: I hope it makes more sense now :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Perhaps:

```
var idGroups = meters
    .SelectMany(m => m.data)
    .GroupBy(d => d.CellID)
    .Select(g => new { CellID = g.Key, UniqueNr = g.Select(m => m.NR).Distinct() });

foreach (var g in idGroups)
    Console.WriteLine("CellID: {0}  Count: {1}", g.CellID, g.UniqueNr.Count());
```

If the `NR`'s don't need to be unique remove the `Distinct`.

Comment: a stupid question but how would you return that to a list or dictionary?

Comment: @user3240428: _what_ list or dictionary?

Comment: public Dictionary<int, string> GetCellIDMCount() fx.

Comment: So why a string for the count?

Comment: public Dictionary<int, int> GetCellIDMCount() then :)

Comment: You just have to append `.ToDictionary(x => x.CellID, x => x.UniqueNr.Count());` to the query above.